# Do vxworks task share data region?

Tags: task, vxworks

In vxworks is the data region shared across all the created tasks like linux threads ?. Also what about the text and code segment which I feel should be separate for each task

Answer (score 6):

In VxWorks 5.x all of the data and text segment are shared across tasks.  There is in effect, a single memory space.

Vxworks 6.x introduced Real Time Processes, which are similar to Linux processes, where the data and code segment is specific to a single process, but all tasks (threads) within a process share those segments.
In VxWorks 6, you can also think of the kernel space as it's own memory space with shared data and code segments for all tasks that run in the kernel.